# Late boarding on the westbound Dacia Express

Tags: trains, romania

I (may) have a westbound ticket in a sleeper on the Dacia Express from Bucharest (station Bucureşti Nord), departure 14:50 to Wien, but would like to board later, perhaps in Sinaia (16:14) or Azuga (16:29).  Can I do this on a ticket from Bucureşti Nord or is my ticket and reservation void as soon as I don't board in Bucureşti Nord?

Comment: Context: I'm going hiking in the mountains after a work trip to Bucharest, and I have to book my return travel from the place of business, but would like to avoid travelling back and forth to Bucharest in-between if I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered on the [CFR Calatori website, under "Sleeping and berth car"](https://www.cfrcalatori.ro/en/travelling-sleeping-berth-car/):

> » **Not presenting at the car when leaving the boarding station**
> When the passenger is not present at the sleeping or berth car, to occupy the seat within 1 (one) hour from the departure of the train at the boarding station (indicated on the bed / berth supplement), the seat is considered to be free (art. 49.4 Uniform Norms for Romanian Railways, approved by OMT no. 655/2007, as subsequently amended and supplemented).

That means that for the Dacia Express, which has a departure from Bucureşti Nord at 14:50, if you do not reach your berth by 15:50 by the latest, the reservation may be considered lost and may be sold again.  It is therefore NOT safe to board at Sinaia (16:14) or Azuga (16:29), but you should in theory be able to board at Ploieşti (15:27) or even Campina (15:49), provided you reach your berth immediately.  The safest, however, is to board at Bucureşti Nord as indicated on your ticket.